# How to create a form dynamically based on a list of ever changing values

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm getting a list of objects with a display name & display value from the backend which changes depending on different requests. I can display this information using a simple *ngFor ... {{object.displayName)): {{object.value}}...
But I need to make this page into a form. 
So my question is how can I create x number of FormControls each with {{object.displayName}} as it's value? And then use the above for loop to match the displayName with the FormControl.
I've looked at using a FormArray but couldn't create one dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an empty FormArray, then iterate the data from backend and push FormCntrols.

```
 form: FormGroup;
 dataFromBackend: [];

 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

 this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      array: this.formBuilder.array([
      ])
    });

ngOnInit() {

  const control = <FormArray>this.form.get('array');

  for (const item of dataFromBackend) {
          control.push(new FormControl(item));
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Adding HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                </thead>
                <ng-container formArrayName="ponderacionFactor">
                <tbody *ngFor="let item of form.get('array')['controls']; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
                    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.value}}</td>
                </tbody>
                </ng-container>
            </table>        
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to create an array of Form Controls. But how could i use this on the html, as in use this html? Plus, and idea on how to use this with a corresponding for loop. Would these FormControlls have a name that I can use? Thanks

Comment: Thanks mate, appreciate it